# How do I insert data into a field of bit data type?

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem when trying to insert a new record into a database. The problem I think is with the bit field. When I assign the value True i get this error:

```
Failed: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 22018 [SQLSTATE] => 22018 [1] 
=> 245 [code] => 245 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]
[SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' 1 ' 
to data type bit. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]
[SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' 1 ' to 
data type bit. ) )
```

but if i change it to false it works. I will show some of my code. I have cut out most of it as i have narrowed it down to this variable:

```
$active = True;
```

here is my insert query.

```
$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO customers(
                customerID,
                registeredDate,
                givenName,
                familyName,
                email,
                password,
                phone,
                mobile,
                property,
                street,
                locality,
                town,
                area,
                postalCode,
                active
            ) 
            VALUES(" .
                $newUser . "," .
                $date . ", ' " .
                $given . " ', ' " .
                $family . " ', ' " .
                $email . " ', ' " .
                $pwd . " ', ' " .
                $phone . " ', ' " .
                $mob . " ', ' " .
                $property . " ', ' " .
                $street . " ', ' " .
                $locality . " ' , ' " .
                $town . " ', ' " .
                $area . " ', ' " .
                $postalcode . " ', ' " .
                $active . " ')";

$stmtInsert = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlInsert);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the `active` field is of `bit` data type.

You don't use any quotation marks around the value being passed for the active field like what you do for customerid field.

Also, I think you have to convert the value *true* / *false* to **1** / **0**.

*Modified code*: Noticed that the single quotes surrounding `" . $active . "` have been removed.

```
$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO customers(customerID, registeredDate, givenName,
                familyName,  email, password, 
                phone, mobile, property, 
                street, locality, town,  
                area, postalCode, active) 
              VALUES(" . $newUser . "," . $date . ", ' " . $given . " ', 
              ' " . $family . " ', ' " . $email . " ', ' " . $pwd . " ', 
              ' " . $phone . " ', ' " . $mob . " ', ' " . $property . " ', 
              ' " . $street . " ', ' " . $locality . " ' , ' " . $town . " ', 
              ' " . $area . " ', ' " . $postalcode . " ', " . $active . ")";
$stmtInsert = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlInsert);
```

I am not sure why it worked with *False* value. I would suggest you to find out how the `INSERT` statement evaluates to after setting all the values. Instead of executing the statement, print the INSERT statement to screen/page and run it manually in the SQL Server Management Studio against the database.